# spring tools suite defaul mvc project web application

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, web-applications, uri

hi i'm trying to change my default home page for another one but i couldn't do it, so i try to redirect the page from the default home page to the one i want, but i get this error 
No mapping found for HTTP request with URI:

> [/myapp/WEB-INF/views/index.html] in DispatcherServlet with name
>   'appServlet'

this is my setup i left everything by default when i create the project with spring tools suite

this is my servlet-contex.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

<!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
<annotation-driven />

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value="" />
</beans:bean>

<context:component-scan base-package="com.proj.myapp" />
```

this is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

this is my deafult home file

home.jsp

```
enter code here 
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
    <%@ page session="false" %>
      <html>
        <head>
          <title>Home</title>
        </head>
              <body>
               <h1>
                Hello world!  
                    <c:redirect url="/indice.html"/>
                </h1>
              </body>
       </html>
```

and this is the page i want to be redirected

```
enter code here 
    <html>

           <body>
            <h1>
                INDICE
            </h1>
           </body>
    </html>
```

and my contoller

```
        @Controller
        public class HomeController {


        @RequestMapping(value = "/")
        public String home() {


        return "home.jsp";
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/indice.html")
        public String indice() {


        return "indice.html";
        }
 }
```

and i get this error

> No mapping found for HTTP request with URI: 
>   [/myapp/WEB-INF/views/indice.html] in DispatcherServlet with name
>   'appServlet'

Answer (score 0):

As from your code suffix property value is blank so you need to pass the type of suffix to this property in in servlet-context.xml.

You have to change it

```
<beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
```

and your indices.html to indices.jsp then it will work.

But if you want to work it with html file but .html files are static and do not require processing by a servlet then it is more efficient, and simpler, to use an  mapping. This requires Spring 3.0.4+.

For example:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/static/" />
```

which would pass through all requests starting with /static/ to the webapp/static/ directory.

So by putting indices.html in webapp/static/ and using return "indices.html"; from your method, Spring should find the view.